# Annoying Busy Cursor when opening gnome related apps

Tags: gnome, cursor

Just installed Ubuntu 22.04.1, I really like it, but there's a weird cursor thing that annoys me.

Here's what happens: when I open gnome apps like (gnome terminal, settings and files) the cursor turns to busy spinning state for less than a second. This doesn't happen when I open other non gnome apps like (nomacs, smplayer and Htop) the arrow of the cursor doesn't change when I open them.

#### Busy cursor screenshot

[image: Busy cursor screenshot]

### Another cursor

[image: Another cursor]

Answer (score 3):

The workaround to avoid this spinning cursor is to turn off startup notify in the launcher of the application. This is done by editing the `.desktop` launcher of the application with a text editor and making sure there is a line that reads

```
StartupNotify=false
```

The issue is caused because the desktop awaits a notification of the application that it has finished starting up, but that does not proceed properly.

To "edit" a `.desktop` launcher, do not edit the system provided file directly. Instead, make a copy in `~/.local/share/applications` or in `/usr/local/share/applications` (depending on whether you want the change for your user only or for the entire system), and edit that copy. `.desktop` launchers installed by the package manager (in `/usr/share/applications` or in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/` for applications installed as a snap may be overwritten on the next update.

Comment: This change is not immediately working because of cache. I had to change the name first: mv octavian.desktop octavian2.desktop, test it. And then change it back: mv octavian2.desktop octavian.desktop